# Apex schedule crontab syntax

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job, cron

I want to schedule a batch to run everyday at 1 am. I've tried the following code as suggested [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm):

```
System.schedule('BatchAccount daily at 5 am', '0 0 1 * * ?', new BatchAccount());
```

But if I view the details of my scheduled job from the UI I see this:

[image: Job Schedule]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just schedule your job through the UI if you are doing something simple like every day at a specific time. Using `system.schedule` makes things needlessly complex.

**Steps To Schedule**

1. Make sure your `Apex Class` implements the `Schedulable` interface.
2. Navigate to `Setup` > `Develop` > `Apex Classes`.
3. Click the <kbd>Schedule Apex</kbd> button.
4. Select your `Apex Class`.
5. Set the schedule you desire.
6. Click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.

See also: **[Schedule Apex](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_schedule_batch_apex.htm&language=en)**.

Comment: Yeah, you should only use cron for complex scheduling. I see it all the time on here.

Comment: Nice wearing of the admin hat, using the tools is way preferable!

Comment: As long as you remember to schedule the job every few months after it expires.

Answer (score 2):

The cron string is correct. The limitation is the GUI configuration screen. It can't correct express any but the most simple of configurations. Your job will run as expected, however.

Comment: Just curious, do you disagree that using `system.schedule` is overkill for a job running at the same time every day? My opinion is `Clicks Not Code` holds strongly here.

Comment: 'Your job will run as expected, however.' I dont know about that...

Comment: @AdrianLarson I generally do agree with "clicks over code." However, assuming you want a daily schedule to run *for all time*, you need code, not clicks. Or, if you want your schedule to run every four hours... etc. The GUI is intentionally restricted, so you *need* to use code for some types of schedules.

Comment: You can set an end date way in the future through the UI. I've definitely set it more than 10 years out. If you're really worried about it, you could set it much further than that. Not as good as *forever*, true. Still, I opt for simplicity here.